# Jenkins linking to my local git repository

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins and git too. I created a remote repository at `github.com` and made a local copy of it.
Then I want to link it through Jenkins. I installed needed plugins for git integration, but I don't know what my local Repository URL is to set it when configuring the new project. Could someone help me where to find it?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

In this case, the URL should start with the file protocol followed by the path to the repository. E.g., `file:///home/rbkcbeqc/dev/git/gitsandbox`.

Comment: See [git plugin for Jenkins fails to clone a repo from local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307938/git-plugin-for-jenkins-fails-to-clone-a-repo-from-local-machine-error-code-128) if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: what about mac file system? Does the prefix file stay?

Answer (score 26):

### Access local git repository in Jenkins docker container

In case somebody wants to connect to a local git repository from a Jenkins which runs in a docker container I would recommend to mount the local git repository folder to the docker image via the Volumes flag (see [Use Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for more details).

To mount your local git repository folder to a Jenkins container run the container with an additional `-v` or `--volume` flag.

The basic docker run statement from the official docker image documentation would then look like.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 
           -v <PATH_TO_LOCAL_GIT_REPO>:<MOUNT_POINT_IN_CONTAINER>:ro 
           jenkins/jenkins:latest
```

The `:ro` option is optional. It will mount the volume as read-only. So you won't be able to write to the repos from the container.

Then you can simply access your git repository via the file protocol.

```
file:///<MOUNT_POINT_IN_CONTAINER>
```

No need to use ssh.

Comment: It seems this solution works, but when I make changes in my git repo on my host machine, they are not reflected in the mounted volume...so I can't really test out how Jenkins responds to changes I make as I go.  Is that correct, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: people who have problems please don't forget to add a slash after file//, like file:///var/project, there are 3 slashes

Answer (score 9):

If you run Jenkins within Docker, one possible solution would be via SSH:

```
ssh://user@IP_of_your_host/path_to_your_project/project_name
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Since it's a local repo it was enough to put `localhost` as IP for me

Comment: Man that works fine,

One need to add a public key generated by jenkins to your local `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_key`

Answer (score 4):

If you did clone a remote repository into local where `Jenkins` is running.

You can just put the path of the local repository then it will work.

For example, `/home/username/local_repository_path`.