# git plugin for Jenkins fails to clone a repo from local machine. Error code 128

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Error:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h file:///home/myuser/path/to/project HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: fatal: 'home/myuser/path/to/project' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have tried the following:

- `chmod 777` to the repo folder(folder containing .git directory)
- `chowned` to `jenkins:jenkins` on the repo folder
- tried to clone into another folder from this local repo folder: this works!

When I run the above command: `/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h file:///home/myuser/path/to/project HEAD` on cmd I get the branches.

My questions are:

1. why is `git ls-remote -h ...` command called when it should be `git clone ...`?
2. How to configure jenkins git plugin to fetch code from local repo

My environment:

RHEL 5.9

Jenkins 1.519 installed as a service(no Web container)

[Git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin)

Comment: Whatever problem you are trying to solve, **`chmod 777` is an atrocious antipattern and a potential security problem.** You should revert this change ASAP.

Comment: I agree!...Please see the selected answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When installing `Jenkins` as a service, by default, `Jenkins` does not create a user directory as in: `/home/jenkins`. Jenkins default home directory is set to `/var/lib/jenkins`. From my work-around, as you would expect, `jenkins` has trouble accessing local resources from other users directory.

I moved my cloned repo under Jenkins default home directory i.e. under `/var/lib/jenkins` so my `Repository URL`in Jenkins Project configuration looks like: `file:///${JENKINS_HOME}/repo/<myprojectname>`

**UPDATE:** 
The above works fine ...but I found a better way to do it from [this blog](http://mwaidyanatha.blogspot.com/2013/03/running-jenkins-under-different-user-in.html#!)

The steps are outlined here:

look up `/etc/init.d/jenkins` script. There are a few `$JENKINS` variables defined
. This should lead you to the `sysconfig` for jenkins i.e. `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`.
Stop your jenkins instance:

`sudo /sbin/service jenkins stop`

Take a backup

`cp /etc/sysconfig/jenkins /etc/sysconfig/jenkins.bak`

In this file, change the following property:

`$JENKINS_USER="<your desired user>"`

Change ownership of all related Jenkins directories:

`chown -R <your desired user>:<your user group> /var/lib/jenkins`

`chown -R <your desired user>:<your user group> /var/cache/jenkins`

`chown -R <your desired user>:<your user group> /var/log/jenkins`

Restart jenkins and that error should disappear

`sudo /sbin/service jenkins start`

This error should go away now!

Comment: thanks.. it works after changing the ownership of those directories to "jenkins" user

Comment: In the latest Ubuntu at least you also need to review other uses of $NAME in the sysconfig/defaults file. Even the reference to the "jenkins.war" file was actually $NAME.war.

Answer (score 8):

It's been a while since this question was asked, but I had this problem today and there are very few resources. Most probably, because people tend to connect to git repositories remotely.

I checked using strace what exactly jenkins was doing and yes, it was a problem with permissions.

But I solved it in a simpler way than answer #2 - by adding jenkins to the git server group - in my case, git1:

`root# gpasswd -a jenkins git1
root# service jenkins restart`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I had already add Jenkins to the git group but I also needed to restart the Jenkins service which I tried from reading your answer, and it worked ! Now I just use /opt/git/repo.git in my Jenkins config and I got rid of the Error code 128.

Answer (score 6):

I'm running Jenkins on Windows and had the same problem. I was able to solve this by having the Jenkins service log in as my user on my laptop.

(Windows 7)

1. Open Task Manager (Ctrl + Shift + Escape)

   1. (Windows 10 only) Click on <kbd>More Details</kbd> in the lower left corner of the pop up window
2. Go to the *Services* tab
3. Click the <kbd>Services...</kbd> button
4. Find "Jenkins" in the list of services
5. Right-click "Jenkins" and click on *Properties*
6. Click the *Log On* tab in the *Jenkins Properties* window
7. Choose *This account:* under *Log on as:*
8. Enter your username and password
9. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>
10. Restart the Jenkins service
11. Then Bob's your uncle.

Comment: if you run with 'java -jar jenkins.war', it's this necessary? thx :)

Comment: @EnriqueSanMartin: It is likely you still might. It all has to do with the permissions of the user running the Java process.

Answer (score 3):

1. Jenkins uses `git clone` command only for the first time when a workspace is configured for a project. Further instances uses the `git ls-remote` command.
2. I had the same issue when I configured Jenkins. It was resolved by playing around with the SSH Keys. This looks like a configuration issue as well. Check if SSH Keys are setup for the Jenkins account.

Also, see the step by step procedure of configuration of SSH in the link provided. This might not give you exact solution, but can point you to the solution.

http://oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/How-to-setup-Jenkins-With-Grails-on-Ubuntu

Comment: as per your link I added jenkins to sudo list `jenkins   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` Unfortunately, it still isn't able to clone repo from local file...thanks again!

Comment: If you are using Jenkins as a user on the OS, did you check to see if you have the SSH keys placed under the %userprofile% directory

Answer (score 0):

I find that the other solutions are a bit "hacky" for me. What I did was move the Jenkins Home folder from /Users/Shared/ to /Users/[myacccount]/. This way, my Jenkins will have access to my repos and to my Android SDK (because that's where I use Jenkins for). Then change the JENKINS_HOME environment variable. I did this by entering the JENKINS_HOME in my .bash_profile (but there are other ways to do this).

Note: I use OSX

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `file:///` you can also use `ssh://` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51741006/2111778):

```
ssh://YOUR_USER@localhost/PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT
```

Note that you need to do the standard ssh setup:

1. Generate a keypair using `ssh-keygen` if you don't already have one in `~/.ssh`
2. Paste private key (default `~/.ssh/id_rsa`) into Jenkins (project settings, git repo, credentials)
3. Paste public key into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`