# Pulling code from Git local repo to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to pull the code from git local repo to Jenkins. How can I do..What should be the repo URL? Is a repo on github mandatory for Jenkins Build?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins linking to my local git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498554/jenkins-linking-to-my-local-git-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github is not mandatory for Jenkins. What it needs is, a git clone URL, so that Jenkins can clone/pull that repo into it's job's workspace to work upon.

Since you have git repo hosted on your local and not on any server, what you need is a .git clone URL of you local file system.

You can go through this link for the same : [GIT clone repo across local file system in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519933/git-clone-repo-across-local-file-system-in-windows)

I still suggest to push your local git repository to any git hosting services and integrate that with Jenkins. It will be easier approach.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh for cutting the clutter !!! Went ahead and got it working !!!