# Jenkins without Git Repository

Tags: user-interface, jenkins, testing, configuration

I have a source code using which I want to test some processes through Jenkins.For that I've installed Jenkins and plugins as well. But I do not have internet access to my machine so I have my source code in a local folder instead of Git.
Please help me to configure Jenkins without git.
Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: I think this will answer your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498554/jenkins-linking-to-my-local-git-repository?rq=1

Comment: Hi @Michael, Thanks for your help. I now got the way how to give the path to the file, but still not sure where to give. Because inside Jenkins Source code management there're only 3 options: 1. None, 2. Git, 3. Subversion.

Answer (score 0):

in the build steps, you can do something like

```
cd C:\users\user\Documents\Projects\
// build here
```

if you're in a different directory, you need to do:

```
cd D:\Projects
D:
// build here
```

But deleting the workspace option won't work now. since your artifacts will be stored in the current directory and the workspace is a different directory. you can add an additional step, in this case, to clean up things or you can change the workspace from the advanced option in the general tab.

[image]