# Jenkins in docker with a local git repo - not registering changes to Jenkinsfile

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I am running a Jenkins instance locally on my machine, using docker.  I want to use this instance to run a pipeline on a local repo, using a Jenkinsfile in the repo.  I am using the Jenkins UI for now as I get better acquainted with Jenkins.

In order to launch a Jenkins instance that has access to my repo, I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53462044/12010984).  I ran this docker command:

```
docker run -p 9090:8080 -p 50000:50000 
           -v /Users/me/Desktop/projects/my_project:/var/my_project
           jenkins/jenkins:latest
```

So I open up to localhost:9090 and set up my Jenkins with username/password, node plugins, etc.  I set up a new pipeline job, and in the Pipeline section I choose

```
- Definition     : Pipeline script from SCM
- SCM            : Git
- Repository URL : file:///var/my_project
```

Jenkins finds the files just fine and is able to run the Jenkinsfile.  However, making changes to the Jenkinsfile, even *in the container* (using vscode), doesn't seem to change the Jenkinsfile that Jenkins is using.  For example, if I started with a Jenkinsfile that says

```
echo "Run this line"
```

But then I edit it to say `echo "Run something else"` and then run the job, I still get the output of "Run this line".  It's almost as though Jenkins is cacheing the Jenkinsfile.  I've tried restarting the container, I've tried adding a new job, nothing seems to work, its like I'm stuck with the version of the file I have when I first `docker run` the container.

How can I try different Jenkins pipelines by editing my Jenkinsfile, given my current setup of Jenkins in a docker container, and a local git repo?

Comment: Did you commit the change or just save the file? No commit, no change

Comment: Wow so dumb.  Committing the changes works.  Can't believe I didn't realize that.  If you don't mind a follow up question:  considering I'm just trying out different pipeline configs from my local repo, how might I set up the jenkins job to just read the Jenkinsfile directly from what's currently on my hard drive for that repo (as opposed to what's commited)?  I.e. make a change to the file, save it, and hit "Build Now", without worrying about committing every time?

Comment: Pretty sure it won't work. Jenkins clones the repo to the job local workspace. It cannot clone what's not committed.